# Численные методы.Метод секущих

Tags: c, численные-методы

Подскажите, правильно ли я реализую метод секущих?

```
void secant(float (*f)(float),  float x1, float x2, float E)
{
    float r, xn,n=0, x0;
    if (f(x1) * f(x2) < 0) {
        do {       
            x0=x2-((f(x2))/((f(x2)-f(x1))/(x2-x1)));
            r =f(x0);    
            x1 = x2;
            x2 = x0;
            n++;
            if (r == 0)
                break;
            xn = x2-((f(x2))/((f(x2)-f(x1))/(x2-x1)));
        } while (fabs(x0-xn) >= E); 
  
        cout << "Root of the given equation=" << x0 << endl;
        cout << "No. of iterations = " << n << endl;
    } else
        cout << "Can not find a root in the given inteval";
}
```

Попытался так : Ответ вывелся тоже верный

```
void secant(float (*f)(float),  float x1, float x2, float E)
{
    float r, xn,n=0, x0;
    if (f(x1) * f(x2) < 0) {
        do {       
            xn=x2-((f(x2))/((f(x2)-f(x1))/(x2-x1)));
            r =f(xn);    
            x1 = x2;
            x2 = x0;
            n++;
            if (r == 0)
                break;
        } while (fabs(x2-xn) >= E); 
  
        cout << "Root of the given equation=" << x0 << endl;
        cout << "No. of iterations = " << n << endl;
    } else
        cout << "Can not find a root in the given inteval";
}
```

Но добавив подсчет итераций во второй вариант стало выводится что попало
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавив подсчет итераций в первый вариант ..вроде бы всё хорошо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем проблема и что я делаю не так в реализации этого метода?

Comment: Вы показываете один код, вывод другого кода и просите угадать что не так в том коде, который вы не показали. Это не логично. Или я что-то упустил?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy подправил.

Comment: x0 - неопределенное значение во втором примере.

Answer (score 0):

У вас как-то хитро написано.

С одной стороны, алгоритм секущих почему-то вы считаете только до тех пор, пока значения функции в краях интервала различаются знаками. Зачем? Метод секущих прекрасно работает даже в тех случаях, когда знак одинаков.

С другой, вы совершенно не проверяете аномальные ситуации - уход в бесконечность, получение `nan`, сближение `f(xn)` и `f(x2)`.

Далее, тот факт. что у вас интервал между `xn` и `x2` меньше эпсилон, ИМХО, не означает, что вы нашли решение. Контрпример придумать с ходу не могу, но нюхом чую )) Нужно проверять, что значение функции по модулю меньше эпсилон.

Я не смог разобраться, что у вас не так, и сделал для примера свою реализацию:

```
struct result_t {
    bool success;
    double result;
    unsigned int f_count;
    unsigned int iter_count;
    string message;

    result_t() : success(false), result(0.0), f_count(0), iter_count(0), message() {}
};

typedef double (*unifunc_t)(double);

result_t secant(unifunc_t f,  double x1, double x2, double E=1e-10, unsigned int maxiter=50)
{
    result_t result;

    if (x1 == x2) {
        result.message = "x1 == x2";
        return result;
    }

    auto y1 = f(x1); result.f_count++;
    if (fabs(y1) < E) {
        result.result = x1;
        result.success = true;
        return result;
    }
    auto y2 = f(x2); result.f_count++;
    if (fabs(y2) < E) {
        result.result = x2;
        result.success = true;
        return result;
    }
    if (fabs(y1 - y2) < E) {
        result.message = "f(x1) almost equals f(x2)";
        return result;
    }

    if (isinf(y1) || isnan(y1) || isinf(y2) || isnan(y2)) {
        result.message = "f(x) is not defined in x1 or x2";
        return result;
    }


    do {
        result.iter_count ++;
        auto df = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
        auto step = y2/df;
        auto xn = x2 - step;
        if (isnan(xn) || isinf(xn)) {
            result.message = "Failed to converge: x out of bounds";
            return result;
        }
        auto yn = f(xn); result.f_count ++;
        if (isnan(yn) || isinf(yn)) {
            result.message = "Failed to converge: f(x) is undefined for " + to_string(xn);
            return result;
        }

        if (fabs(yn) < E) {
            result.result = xn;
            result.success = true;
            return result;
        }
        if (fabs(yn-y2) < E) {
            result.message = "Failed to converge: f(x_n) almost equal f(x_n_1)";
            return result;
        }
        x1 = x2; y1 = y2;
        x2 = xn; y2 = yn;
    } while (result.iter_count < maxiter);
    result.success = false;
    result.result = x2; 
    result.message = "Failed to converge, last f(x) == " + to_string(y2);
    return result;
}
```

Как вы видите, сопуствующего кода больше, чем собственно вычислений. Сразу скажу, что в реальной жизни вот так не пишут:

```
        auto df = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
        auto step = y2/df;
```

По-хорошему тут надо рассматривать несколько случаев, чтобы не потерять точность.

Примеры счёта.

```
double x2_minus_2(double x) {
    return x*x-2;
}

double polinomial(double x) {
    return ((((x - 1)*x+2)*x - 3)*x + 4)*x - 5;
}

double x2_plus_1(double x) {
    return x*x+1;
}

double ex_plus_1(double x) {
    return exp(x)+1;
}

void solve(unifunc_t f, double x1, double x2, string text) {
    auto result = secant(f, x1, x2);
    cout << text;
    if (!result.success) {
        cout << "Failed: " << result.message 
            << ", iterations " << result.iter_count
            << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "x:" << result.result 
            << ", function called " << result.f_count << " times"
            << ", iterations: " << result.iter_count 
            << ", f(x): " << f(result.result)
            <<  endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    solve(x2_minus_2, 1.0, 2.0, "sqrt(2): ");
    solve(polinomial, 1.0, 2.0, "x^5-x^4+2x^3-3x^2+4x-5=0: ");
    cout << endl;
    solve(x2_minus_2, -1.0, 1.0, "sqrt(2), x1 = -1, x2 = 1: ");
    solve(x2_plus_1, 0.0, 2.0, "x^2 + 1 == 0: ");
    solve(ex_plus_1, 1.0, 2.0, "e^x + 1 == 0: ");
    return 0;
}
```

В первом примере извлекаем квадратный корень из 2, во втором ищем корень многочлена `x^5-x^4+2x^3-3x^2+4x-5`. Остальные демонстрируют, как ломается метод секущих. В третьем начальные значения совпадают, то есть секущая параллельна оси Ox. В четвёртом кривая становится слишком горизонтальной (экспонента). В пятом корень не существует (`x^2 + 1 = 0`)

```
sqrt(2): x:1.41421, function called 8 times, iterations: 6, f(x): 8.88178e-16
x^5-x^4+2x^3-3x^2+4x-5=0: x:1.26626, function called 10 times, iterations: 8, f(x): -2.11386e-13

sqrt(2), x1 = -1, x2 = 1: Failed: f(x1) almost equals f(x2), iterations 0
x^2 + 1 == 0: Failed: Failed to converge, last f(x) == 1.585817, iterations 50
e^x + 1 == 0: Failed: Failed to converge: f(x_n) almost equal f(x_n_1), iterations 6
```